# js HTML Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am not able to pull through a set of text if the checkbox is checked. JS and HTML below... Prob a simple fix - but I am lost that this is not functioning.

//js

```
function getTrainerExp()

{
    var trainerexp="None";
    //Get a reference to the form id="courseform"
    var theForm = document.forms["courseform"];
    //Get a reference to the checkbox id="includeexp"
    var includeexp = theForm.elements["includeexp"];

    //If they checked the box set trainerexp to ACMEEXP
    if(includeExp.checked==true)
    {
        trainerexp="ACMEXP";
    }
    //return the trainer expenses
    return trainerexp;
}


function calculateExp()
{
     var expense = getTrainerExp () ;

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('trainerexp').checked;

    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Please Include   " +expense;

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
<form action="" id="courseform" onsubmit="return false;">
<div>
 <p>
<label for='includeexp' class="inlinelabel">If course delivery is at customer site include trainer travel costs and expenses</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="includeexp" name='includeexp' onclick="calculateExp()" />
</p>

<div id="trainerexp"></div>
```

CSS entry for trainerexp

```
#wrap div#trainerexp
{
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#ff0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use document.getElementById ?

```js
function getTrainerExp()

{
    var trainerexp="None";
    //Get a reference to the form id="courseform"
    var theForm = document.forms["courseform"];
    //Get a reference to the checkbox id="includeexp"
    var includeExp = document.getElementById('includeexp');

    //If they checked the box set trainerexp to ACMEEXP
    if(includeExp.checked==true)
    {
        trainerexp="ACMEXP";
    }
    //return the trainer expenses
    return trainerexp;
}


function calculateExp()
{
     var expense = getTrainerExp () ;

    
   document.getElementById("trainerexp").innerHTML = "Please Include   " +expense;

}
```

```css
#wrap div#trainerexp
{
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#ff0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<form action="" id="courseform" onsubmit="return false;">
<div>
 <p>
<label for='includeexp' class="inlinelabel">If course delivery is at customer site include trainer travel costs and expenses</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="includeexp" name='includeexp' onclick="calculateExp()" />
</p>

<div id="trainerexp"></div>
```

Comment: This worked - thanks for the post - much appreciated !! :)

Comment: you are welcome. If you find this correct answer, you can mark it as answer.